# Installed App Detection: How can I scan and list phones in the vicinity (WiFi Direct) based on apps installed?

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct

I am building an app which intends to connect, using wifi direct, with users who have this particular app installed on their phones as well. I would like to know how this app installed in my phone would be able to only scan for devices with this particular app installed.

Basically I would like to filter out the phones in the vicinity (w.r.t. wifi range) and display only those with this particular app installed.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use pre-association service discovery. On android, JB exposes new service discovery API to accomplish this.

Comment: What is the method for devices lower than API 16? With no service descovery?